# Pandas Dataframe overwrites with each loop

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, beautifulsoup, overwrite

I'm trying to append a dataframe with every loop. Unfortunately the created list is always overwritten by the new output...

```
 for x in link_href_list: 
    urllib.request.urlopen(x)
    html = urlopen(x)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")    
    table=bs.find('tbody')
    rows = table.tr.next_siblings
    list_rows = []
    for row in rows:
        a=row.find('td').get_text().strip()
        list_rows.append(a)
    list_rows = pd.Series(list_rows)
list_rows.to_frame()
```

I need a dataframe that creates a new column with pandas in each iteration...

Comment: It is overwritten because your variable name of the empty list (`list_row`) is inside the first for-loop.  `for x in link_href_list: ` ever iteration of x will overwrite `list_rows`

Answer (score 0):

See, if your list values are of the same length in each iteration, then it shouldn't be that difficult. All you need to do is while creating the Dataframe, supply column names and it should be good

```
pd.DataFrame(list_rows, columns=('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'))
```

You shouldn't need to create each subsequent iteration values into a series, i.e. you don't need this line:

```
list_rows = pd.Series(list_rows)
```

I hope this should help you.
If in case, your number of values are different each time, then it might have to be handled in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, unfortunately the list values have a different length with each iteration.